# Android Navigation Drawer Fragment Not Showing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have implemented a navigation drawer in my application, The application is a tabbed layout and I think this is where the problem is coming from.

AT the moment I have a listener on the items in the Nav drawer to launch a new fragment when pressed. The issue is that when I press one of the items the fragment doesnt seem to load and the current fragment just goes blank.

How do I set the layout of the fragment to launch once the item has been selected? As my current method doesnt seem to be working. The below shows my current attemp where `R.id.viewpager` is what I am trying to replace. Is there a way of just launching the fragments layout and completely replacing the layout with the new fragments layout?

**onDrawerItemSelected**

```
@Override
public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
    switch (position)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        case 1:
            fragment = new FavouritesFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_favourites);
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new HelpFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.title_help);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.viewpager, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        // set the toolbar title
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which position you select? When you select 0, looks like a new activity is started instead. Could this be the problem you face?

Comment: For case 0 yes it is a new activity created I was using activities but I thought using fragments would be better and a smoother transition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.viewpager, fragment);
```

You don't replace the viewpager, you set current item for the viewPager. You should have a `PagerAdapter` that defines which fragment to show for the position.

Comment: But would replacing the view not be a simpler solution if it was to work correctly?